# Easy to use Wordpress restaurant style menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm making some changes to a client's Wordpress site. They sell baked goods, and want to be able to do a menu similar to this one -

http://www.georgetowncupcake.com/menu.html

I can think of a couple ways to do it, some CSS for positioning and jQuery for visibility, but I want it to be easy for them to add and modify menu items. I'm not sure what would be the best way to do that. Is there a Wordpress plugin that I could use? They would need to be able to add items to the menu, as well as adding the photos and descriptions, without having to really edit any HTML. I tried posting this on the Wordpress forums but didn't receive any replies.

Comment: It's just a big old table with hyperlinks and hover effects.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a category called menu, and implement a custom post type of menu item. Be careful with naming conventions though, menu-item will clash with WordPress nav menus.

Once you have created the custom post type, you add some custom fields to it, ie name, description, price. Properly displayed using a category-specific page template, you now have an awesome looking menu that will grow, shrink, and change as your client needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll pardon the self-promotion, you might want to take a look at my [Food and Drink Menu plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/food-and-drink-menu/) on the WordPress repository. It will implement all of the backend custom post types and data-handling you need to let your client add menu items with photos and descriptions.

By default, it's not really designed to output the menu in the specific layout you want (day-by-day columns in a table). But such a configuration could be accomplished by making use of the plugin's templates system. You can learn more about that by reading [this tutorial](http://themeofthecrop.com/2014/01/28/customize-restaurant-menu-templates/).

Don't hesitate to use the support forum for the plugin at the WordPress.org repository. I'm happy to help out as much as I can to get you where you need to go with the plugin.